# inotifywait secretely consumes a lot of memory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, inotifywait

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
16384
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
128
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
1048576
```

Right after computer restart I had 1GB of RAM consumed. After 20-30 minutes (having just 1 terminal opened) I had 6GB RAM used **and growing**, however none of the processes seemed to be using so much memory (according to `htop` and `top`). When I've killed `inotifywait` process memory was not freed but stopped growing. Then I've restarted PC, killed inotifywait right away and memory usage stopped at 1GB.

I have 2 hard drives, one is 1TB and second is 2TB. Was `inotifywait` somehow caching those or in general is it normal that it caused such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the Linux disk cache at work](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/), it is not a memory leak in `inotifywait` or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I've accepted previous answer because it explains what's going on. However I have some second thoughts regarding this topic. What the page is basically saying is "caching doesn't occupy memory because this memory can at any point be taken back, so you should not worry, you should not panic, you should be grateful!". Well ... I'm not. I believe there should be some decent but at the same time hard limit for caching.

The idea behind this process was good -> "let's not waste user time and cache everything till we have space". However what this process is actually doing in my case is **wasting my time**. Currently I'm working on Linux which is running in virtual machine. Since I have a lot jira pages opened, a lot terminals in many desktops, some tools opened and etc I don't want to open all that stuff every day, so I just save virtual machine state instead of turning it off at the end of the day. Now let's say that my stuff occupies 4GB RAM. What will happen is that 4GB will be written into my hard drive after I save state and then 4GB will have to be loaded into RAM when I start virtual machine. Unfortunately that's only theory. In practice due to inotifywait which will happily fill my 32 GB RAM I have to wait 8 times longer for saving and restoring virtual machine. Yes my RAM is "fine" as the page is saying, yes I can open different app and I will not hit OOM but at the same time caching is wasting my time.

If the limit was decent let's say 1GB for caching then it would not be so painful. I think if I would have VM on HDD instead of SSD it would took forever to save the state and I would probably not use it at all.